# nosuchsessionerror: invalid session id - Docker for linux | Protractor

Tags: angular, linux, docker, protractor

I am running into error while running protractor e2e on linux Docker container. My e2e script worked once and started failing. Reboot did not work. Please advise

Error:

```
nosuchsessionerror: invalid session id
```

Chrome configuration:

```
chromeOptions: {
      perfLoggingPrefs: {
        enableNetwork: true
      },
      prefs: { 'safebrowsing.enabled': 'false' },
      args: [
        '--incognito',
        '--start-maximized',
        '--headless',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--window-size=1920,1080',
        '--ignore-certificate-errors'
        '--enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess',
        '--remote-debugging-port=4444'
      ],
      excludeSwitches: ['enable-automation'],
      useAutomationExtension: false
    }
```

Comment: I think it is ''goog:chromeOptions" and not "chromeOptions". This rename changed a while back.  If your chrome options are set incorrectly for headless, I believe you get a no session error.  My capabilities is `cap['goog:chromeOptions']['args'] = ['--headless', '--disable-gpu'];`

Comment: still getting the same error with the arguments set